# How to use Push notification on ios apps in Ionic 1

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am new In Ionic. I want to use Cordova plugin FCM in ionic apps for Push notification use Bundle id. Android Is work fine But IOS not work. Plese help Me?

Comment: do you tried to use "onesignal api" ? is much simple.. here's a plugin dedicated for : onesignal-cordova-plugin

Comment: btw i used it for both android and ios apps with ionic, it works fine ;)

Comment: ok, Thanks For reply. Let me Check